# With the release of Java 18, UTF-8 is the default charset now. Does it imply that char data type is no more UTF-16?

Tags: java, types, char, utf

I understand that Java follows UTF-16 for the char data type. But the new update in Java 18 - Default charset for the standard Java APIs is UTF-8.
Does this update have any impact on the char data type encoding format? I also understand that UTF-8 is a variable-width encoding that can accommodate characters up to 4 bytes. What is the size of the char data type after Java 18? And does it still adhere to UTF-16 or moved to UTF-8?

Comment: No, char is still UTF-16. That isn't what is meant by making UTF-8 the default, at all. It means that UTF-8 will be the default instead of Windows-1252 (or whatever). The char data type has not changed in any way whatsoever.

Comment: For reference: [JEP 400: UTF-8 by Default](https://openjdk.org/jeps/400).

Comment: A charset is a rule for converting between Strings and bytes.  That's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the change in default character encoding does *not* affect the internals of `char`/`Character`, nor does it affect the intervals of `String`.

I suggest you read the official documentation, [*JEP 400: UTF-8 by Default*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/400). The motivation and the details are explained *thoroughly*.

The change made in Java 18 affects mainly input/output. So this includes the older APIs and classes for **reading and writing files**. Some of the newer APIs and classes were already defaulting to UTF-8. JEP 400 seeks to make this default consistent throughout the bundled libraries.

One particular issue called out in the JEP regards Java source code files that were saved with a non-UTF-8 encoding and compiled with an earlier JDK. Recompiling on JDK 18 or later may cause problems.

---

By the way, let me remind you that `char`/`Character` has been legacy since Java 5, essentially broken since Java 2. As a 16-bit type, `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters.

To work with individual characters, use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers. Look for  `codePoint` methods added to classes including `String`, `StringBuilder`, `Character`, etc.